# SSRS Report with Comma Delimited Parameter Input

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I want to create a parameter filter ("Text" datatype) on my SSRS report where users can supply customerIDs seperated by comma or semicolons.

Is there any way I can achieve above ?
Is there any way to supply all customer Ids with comma seperated by default ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special you need to do to a Text parameter to make it capable of accepting a comma-delimited string.

To supply the default value, you need to create a dataset that returns the default value you want to use.   Then use the dataset for the default value.

Comment: How can i convert that comma delimited string in to multi-select parameter ?

Comment: You don't.   If you want to set the default values of a multi-select parameter, then you use a dataset with one row per value, and set a column of the dataset to be the default value of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using a multiple value parameter `@customers` which you set the Available Values to something like:

```
SELECT customerID, customerName
FROM Customers
```

If you also set the Default Values to the same query then all customers will be selected. Then you have a query like this for your main report dataset:

```
SELECT *
FROM Bills
WHERE customerID IN (@customers)
```